# converting from windows-1255 to utf8 creates question marks for special chars

Tags: ajax, encoding, utf-8, hebrew, windows-1255

I have a string in hebrew which is encoded as windows-1255, passed with POST (by jquery AJAX) and then inserted into my DB which is encoded with "hebrew_general_ci".

If i don't put the following code before the insert:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

The string looks like this:

> ׳×׳׳™׳׳•׳× ׳׳¢׳‘׳“

If i **do** put the code above before the insert, the string comes out alright, but special characters are replaced with question marks, something like this:

> לוח אם™

becomes:

> לוח אם?

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this for a few days now with no success...
Help would be great.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `hebrew` charset [does not include the `™` symbol](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.hebrew_general_ci.html). You could use the `utf8` charset instead.